# Show item at random from one array when another separate item in a different array is clicked while also removing that item from the first array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, for-loop

I am working on my first real project, a "Hangman" style game. I am trying to have this action take place and am not sure where I am going wrong: If a 'wrong letter' is clicked, show one of the 'body parts' at random and remove from the array so it cannot repeat itself.

```js
let wrongAmount = 0
let wrongLettersArray = ["#alphabetLetterA", "#alphabetLetterB", "#alphabetLetterC", "#alphabetLetterD", "#alphabetLetterE", "#alphabetLetterF", "#alphabetLetterG", "#alphabetLetterH", "#alphabetLetterJ", "#alphabetLetterK", "#alphabetLetterM", "#alphabetLetterN", "#alphabetLetterQ", "#alphabetLetterR", "#alphabetLetterU", "#alphabetLetterV", "#alphabetLetterW", "#alphabetLetterX", "#alphabetLetterY", "#alphabetLetterZ"]
let bodyPartsArray = ["#losingTorso", "#losingRightArm", "#losingLeftArm", "#losingRightLeg", "#losingLeftLeg"]
let correctLettersArray = ["#correctLetterP", "#correctLetterI", "#correctLetterS", "#correctLetterT", "#correctLetterO", "#correctLetterL"]

function wrongGuess() {
    $(wrongLettersArray).on('click', function () {
        $(bodyPartsArray).show()
        wrongGuess()
    })
}

//if a wrong letter is clicked show one of the body parts at random
//remove from list so it cannot repeat
//add 1 to the wrong amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that it never gets executed. You need to set up your code to run, but because you never execute the function outside of the function itself, it never sets up the watcher.

You can do so like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  wrongGuess();
});
```

Unfortunately, the code you wrote doesn't correctly do what you need it to do, so I've provided the solution for you as follows.

First, I set up some basic HTML to illustrate bad and good letters:

```
<h2>wrong</h2>
<button id="a">A</button>
<button id="b">B</button>

<h2>correct</h2>
<button id="p">P</button>
<button id="s">S</button>

<hr>

<h1 id="torso">torso</h1>
<h1 id="right-arm">right arm</h1>

<hr>

wrong count: <span id="wrong">0</span>
```

Then, I set up a function to hide all the body parts initially:

```
function hideAllBodyParts() {
  var bodyPartsSelector = bodyPartsArray.join(', ');

  $(bodyPartsSelector).hide();
}
```

You cannot pass an array to jQuery as a selector, it needs to be a string, i.e. `'#a, #b'` instead of `['#a', '#b']`.

Then your main function that shows one body part at a time and increments the wrong count:

```
function watchForWrongGuesses() {
  // Your selector needs to be a string, e.g. '#a, #b' not an array ['#a', '#b']
  var wrongLettersSelectors = wrongLettersArray.join(', ');

    $(wrongLettersSelectors).on('click', function () {
      // Choose one body part and show it
      var bodyPart = bodyPartsArray.pop();
      $(bodyPart).show();

      // Increment wrong count
      wrongAmount++;
      $('#wrong').text(wrongAmount);
    });
}
```

Then, the final but most important part is linking it up on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  hideAllBodyParts();
  watchForWrongGuesses();
});
```

This method hides all the body parts initially and then sets up the watcher for the button clicks.

Solution: https://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/xmOgJj

Comment: Wow! I cannot thank you enough that makes so much sense, you are a great teacher! Just one question... when you say, "You need to set up your code to run, but because you never execute the function outside of the function itself, it never sets up the watcher." 

Is that what is being fixed by the $(document).ready(function () ?

Comment: Yes @cameron-bret, that's what I mean. You can read more about it in the [jQuery documentation for document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). If you thought my answer was helpful, feel free to accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to pick an item from the body parts array and remove it so it can't be chosen again? You could use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for that.

```
const ar = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * ar.length)
const item = ar.splice(idx, 1)

console.log(item, ar)
```

In the above, we have an array (that would be your body parts array in this case). Then we pick an index, which is somewhere within the length of that array. Then, splice removes the item from the array at that index and returns it.

Comment: Thank you that makes a huge difference! I will do some more research on that method, thanks again!